# ¿ Usar o no usar margin_start?

Tags: android

muchas veces al darle un margen izquierdo a una vista mediante el atributo xml 'android:marginLeft' android studio me marca un warning diciendo que considere añadir tambien android:marginStart.

Cuando lo añado con el mismo valor el warning desaparece.

Entiendo que marginStart es para apis superiores a la 17, entonces la razon de usarlo es esa?
MarginLeft para apis inferiores al 17 y marginStart para superiores a 17, también entiendo que marginLeft funciona en las superiores al 17, entonces ¿Por qué me lo recomienda? ¿Cuál es su función?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La finalidad es soportar la opción RTL (right to left). Desde el api 17, Android da soporte a los lenguajes que se escriben de derecha a izquierda como el árabe. En ese sentido, si lo que quieres es crear un margen antes del comienzo del texto, con margin-start se creará siempre al principio independientemente del idioma. En el manifest tienes una opción supportsRtl para activar/ desactivar esas opciones.
Un saludo

Comment: Ok ya lo he entendido, gracias